# T-SQL : delete from select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation like this:

table_Associazione

```
ID     Cod     Descr
--------------------
001    CAR1    Fiat
002    CAR1    Fiat
003    CAR1    Fiat
004    CAR1    Fiat
005    CAR2    Opel
```

table_cars

```
ID     Name    Descr
--------------------
001    Tipo    4 ruote
002    Panda   4 ruote
003    Alfa    4 ruote
004    Beta    4 ruote
005    tera    3 ruote
```

I need to delete all records (in this case 001-004) from the table `table_cars` where `table_Associazione.Cod = CAR1`.

I think this is what I need:

```sql
delete from 
(select * 
 from td_cars 
 inner join tb_Associazione on tb_Associazione.ID = td_cars.ID 
 where tb_Associazione.Cod = 'CAR1')
```

I ask if theoretically this is the correct way and if no please suggest what is the best way to do it.

Thanks !

Comment: You don't `DELETE` from a subquery, you `DELETE` from an object.

Comment: What happened when you tested your query?

Comment: @Larnu Of course you can delete from a subquery, it just has to be a single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete * from table_cars a
    inner join table_Associazione b 
       on b.id = a.id   
where a.cod='CAR1'
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is a `where` clause:

```
delete c from td_cars c
    where exists (select 1
                  from tb_Associazione a 
                  where a.ID = c.ID and a.Cod = 'CAR1'
                 );
```

Comment: I think your solution is correct only one question:  if there are > 500.000 records this method is fast?

Comment: @user3449922 . . . Assuming you have an index on `tbAssociazione(Id, Cod)` then the performance is really based on the number of rows being deleted.  It could take a lot of time, or not much time at all.  500,000 rows is not that many so it shouldn't hang.